# The app on google glass run very slowly

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-glass

I have used Bluetooth client server connection to connect Google Glass with Android phone. But when the application runs the app on glass runs so slowly which affect connection and the app on android phone consequently runs slowly.
Also, in logcat window when the google glass app is run I see this message continuously:

```
  8122-8142/com.morkout.nbsocial D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1197K, 34% free 8595K/12924K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
```

Comment: It means you're allocating too many objects that are not long-living. You could post a snippet of your code if you want more precision. You can also run the "allocation tracking" mechanism on Android Studio or Eclipse to see where are these allocations

Comment: Maybe you are doing too much work `Main Thread` (anything related with network perhaps)...